# Matching 5 couples in a tennis tournament

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say there are 5 men (Arthur, Bob, Charlie, David and Earl) and there are 5 women (Francine, Grace, Heather, Isabella and Jessie), who want to participate in a mixed-doubles tennis tournament. The ladies were given the option to name up to two men with whom they certainly didn't want to form a couple. These exclusions were [Lady - man]:

- Francine-Arthur, Earl
- Grace-Charlie, David
- Heather-Arthur, Earl
- Isabella-Bob
- Jessie-Charlie

In how many ways is it possible to form 5 couples, while respecting the ladies' wishes? And given that all possibilities have an equal chance of being chosen, what is the chance that two specific people (for example, Arthur and Jessie) form a couple?

---

As for the number of combinations, I think I should observe the total number of combinations ($5! = 120$), minus the number of combinations which contain one of the restrictions. However, doing that would result in subtracting too many combinations, since some of them contain multiple restrictions. So how would I solve a question like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would create a table like the following:

```
     F     G     H     I     J
  ------+-----+-----+-----+-----
A    x  |     |  x  |     |
  ------+-----+-----+-----+-----
B       |     |     |  x  |
  ------+-----+-----+-----+-----
C       |  x  |     |     |  x
  ------+-----+-----+-----+-----
D       |  x  |     |     |
  ------+-----+-----+-----+-----
E    x  |     |  x  |     |
```

Then I would observe columns F and H, which can take values B,C,D. So there are 3 main cases: (1.FB-HC same as FC-HB, 2.FB-HD same as FD-HB and 3.FC-HD same as FD-HC). For each one it's easy to calculate by hand the remaining possible pairs:

- FB-HC or FC-HB (4 each)
- FB-HD or FD-HB (2 each)
- FC-HD or FD-HC (4 each)

So the total number of valid combinations is $2\cdot(4+2+4)=20$.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think writing out all the solutions would be so easy.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something similar, but to check my work (if time wasn't a concern) pursue a more brute-force method. I would list the possible partners for each of the five women (i.e., B/C/D, A/B/E, B/C/D, A/C/D/E, A/B/D/E) and list all the possible combinations. The key to a method like this is having a organizing principle, to make sure you hit every possibility once and don't miss anything. I would work left to right, and put the highest alphabetical option in each, then iterate on the rightmost as much as possible. Once I had exhausted those combinations, move one left, pick the next possible option, and iterate again. So the highest option for F is B, which leaves A for G, then C for H, D for I, E for J (BACDE). Without changing any of the first four, the fifth can't be changed, so move one left and pick the next possible option for I (E) and see what options that leaves for J. There's only one, so this gives BACED and nothing more. Move left again, and set the first three to BAD--. Since J can't be paired with C, this can only give BADCE, and then move again. Hopefully you can see the pattern at this point -- this gives a final list of:
BACDE, BACED, BADCE, BECAD, BECDA, BEDCA, CABDE, CABED, CADEB, CBDAE, CBDEA, CEBAD, CEBDA, CEDAB, DABCE, DACEB, DBCAE, DBCEA, DEBCA, DECAB.
This is in fact 20 combinations, so the answer above me is also right, but for problems like this with a relatively limited number of possibilities, I prefer to make sure I'm right by going through and finding them all.